# Mobile devices displaying different widths from same domain

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

[image: different screen widths]

So, as you can see from the screenshot I am loading the same website from the same domain on my Galaxy S2.

The website on the top is the static html file that was created during initial development and has a url of the following domain.testdomain.com/template/index.html. It works correctly on all devices when viewed on the device itself and in the Google Chrome Dev Tools Emulator.

I then moved the site from the static HTML to our CMS framework with a url of the following: domain.testdoamin.com, and it works fine on the desktop and the tablet, but the phone (any device) does not work properly.

The phone widths are being reported differently from the two sites. The static html displays a width of 320 pixels, which causes the correct media query to kick in. The CMS framework site reports a device with of 980 pixels which causes the media query to not kick in.

I am using this simple JS to find the widths:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    $('#width').text("innerWdth: " + $(window).innerWidth() );
});
});
```

I do not understand why the same device reports different widths from different urls. I am loading the style sheets in the same order on both sites. Unfortunately I am not able to grant anyone direct access to the domains as they are restricted behind a firewall.

If there is more information that is needed please let me know and I will be happy to furnish as much information as I can.

I am using Foundation 5 as a framework.

Comment: Do you have any meta view port definitions set in your CMS template somewhere?

Comment: @mituw16 - Wow. Amazing. I don't know how I forgot to copy the meta viewport tag over from the static file to the CMS file, but that certainly solved the issue, and I feel pretty stupid at this point :) . Thank you so much. Please add your reply as a suggestion and I will mark it as a solution.